# node-webkit and html5 video

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, node-webkit

I am working to develop a desktop application for PC using node-webkit.  When I run the app with node-webkit everything works great with the exception of the mp4 videos.  The html 5 video box pops up, but it is pure white and the controls are grayed-out in the same way it does if I provide a bad file path and run the app in chrome.  An example piece of my index.html file:

```
            <div data-role="popup" id="popupVideo" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" data-tolerance="15,15" class="ui-content">
                <video width="497" height="298" style="max-width:100%;" controls>
                <source src="base/tutorialvideos//General_Tutorial.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
                </video> 
            </div>




            <div class="ui-btn ui-btn-right">
                <a href="#popupVideo" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-inline="true">Tutorial</a>
            </div>
```

I double-checked the file path several times, and tried all combinations of /, //, \, \ just to be sure.  I tried using the full file path instead of the relative with the same results.

I then used a format converter to change one of the videos from .mp4 to .ogv with the same results.

What is really curious, is that I am pretty sure that it IS seeing the videos, because with the code as is posted above, the controls are semi-responsive.  I can toggle between play and pause and drag the slider.  When I drag the slider to the end, it shows the exact run-time of the video, but still no audio or video.

It just occured to me that jquery mobile could be messing it up, so I'll post this and run a test with pure html 5.

Thanks is advance for any info.

Comment: You can use wcjs-player. More details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797828/node-webkit-how-to-play-avi-videos/36361961#36361961).

Answer (score 3):

node-webkit only supports patent "free" codecs out of the box. You can however enable mp4/h264 support which is described here: [Using MP3 & MP4 (H.264) using the video & audio tags.](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Using-MP3-%26-MP4-%28H.264%29-using-the--video--%26--audio--tags.).

Comment: Just adding the @richapps answer. Copying `ffmpegsumo.dll` from a 32-bit Chrome is the quickest way to test mp3/mp4. But do pay attention to licensing requirements.

Comment: I copied the ffmpegsumo.so file (on a mac) from Chrome to Node-Webkit, only to discover it was already there. But node-webkit still doesn't play mp4 files. What's going wrong?

Comment: You need to replace the file with the one from Chrome. The file that comes with node-webkit does not support mp4.

Comment: The link appears to have changed to https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Using-MP3-&-MP4-(H.264)-using-the--video--&--audio--tags